# How to do a custom sort of SQL data using Cursor & Loader?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-cursor, android-loader

I have some data in a SQLite database and i want to provide basic search capabilities in a listview.

Here is an example of search query I want to be able to solve :

1) Example of sqlite data :

> - ad
> - bc
> - cd
> - d
> - da
> - ec

2) Input & wanted output :

> - a -> [ ad , da ]
> - d -> [ d , da , ad , cd ]
> - c -> [ cd, bc , ec ]

I already thought of a few things but nothing really ok :

1. Full Text Search : I cannot modify the input db file so I think I cannot use it
2. one sqlite query (`name LIKE ?% OR name LIKE %?%`) : not sorted. Perhaps another query I am not aware can be figured out
3. two differents queries (`name LIKE ?%` and then `name LIKE %?%`) : but how to implement it with a content provider ? CursorWrapper ? MergeCursor ? custom Loader ?

I have seen a lot of examples but nothing useful for my custom search.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit :** Query on `d` should give [ d , da , ad , cd ].

**The custom sort order I want is** : LIKE pattern% AND then LIKE %pattern% (for example `socks` should come before `a pair of socks`)

Comment: `SELECT name FROM items WHERE name LIKE '%a%'` does not work?

Comment: Doesn't d input result should be [d, ad, cd, da]?

Comment: @user1759572 1) it does not rank the results (d is not before ad). 2) you are right

Comment: how would you like to rank them? by order in db? May be you need Full Text search query for a name column?

Comment: @user1759572 I added a few details. Can I use FTS without modifying the db ?

Comment: Depends what are you calling a 'modifying db'. If you are taking that you can not write to it at all then no, if you can't change old schemas then yes, just add an index or index virtual tables.

Comment: I am using an input db copied from the assets so perhaps I can add an index after copying it, but I am not really aware of how to do this. thanks.

Comment: try the hack I added as an answer.

Comment: To use FTS in sqlite you need to 1. create FTS3 table like 'CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE items_fts USING fts3(name)' 2. 'INSERT INTO items_fts SELECT name FROM items' to insert data to new FTS table. the problem is that the insert is kind of slow if you have a lot of rows. On ranking of your search value check http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#appendix_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some hack for your requirements:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.name
FROM (select *, 1 as sec from items WHERE name LIKE 'd%'
union
select *, 2 as sec from items WHERE name LIKE '%d%') as t 
ORDER BY t.sec ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The [CursorLoader constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html#CursorLoader%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29)'s  last parameter is `sortOrder` - add the `name` column as your `sortOrder` to sort the resulting set (note that leaving it blank, as [SQLiteDatabase.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) may lead to an unsorted order).

Comment: thanks but I want a custom order : `socks` before `pair of socks` for example